# ASP.NET MVC 5 Data is NULL Due To Network Related Instance

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am getting the value from text field but can not find the reason of not getting saved in the variable.

```
var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email ,Email = model.Email};
```

`user` is `null` despite Email contains the value. I have found it through debugging.

```
{
Line 81:       var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email ,Email = model.Email};

Line 82:       var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
Line 83:       if (result.Succeeded)
Line 84:       {
```

Line 82 is the error.
Below is the code.

```
var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email ,Email = model.Email};

var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    var checkingAccount = new CheckingAccount
    {
        FirstName = model.FirstName,
        LastName = model.LastName,
        AccountNumber = "111014005",
        Balance = 0,
        ApplicationUserId = user.Id

    };
    db.CheckingAccounts.Add(checkingAccount);
    db.SaveChanges();
```

Stack Trace:

> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file
>   specified]
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to
>   locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server
>   Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime
>   feature is enabled.)]
>
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +414
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection) +196
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +146
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +16
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +94
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +110    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.b__36(DbConnection
>   t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c) +10
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget
>   target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext,
>   Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +72
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection
>   connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +360
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32()
>   +426    System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0() +10
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1
>   operation) +189
>
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action
>   operation) +78
>
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection
>   sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +175
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection
>   sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +557
>
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable`1
>   commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, String
>   createDatabaseScript) +86
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection
>   connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection
>   storeItemCollection) +164
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDatabase(DbConnection
>   connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection
>   storeItemCollection) +76
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase() +134
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection
>   connection) +119
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action
>   mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) +142
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String
>   targetMigration) +78
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext
>   internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext)
>   +89    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase(ObjectContext
>   objectContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +116
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState
>   existenceState) +218
>
>   System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext
>   context) +149
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__e()
>   +76    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action
>   action) +60
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
>   +357    System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext
>   c) +7
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
>   +110    System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1
>   action) +198
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
>   +73    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType) +28
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +53
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
>   +15    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
>   +38    System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(IQueryable`1
>   source, Expression`1 predicate, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   +138    System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(IQueryable`1
>   source, Expression`1 predicate) +133
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.d__6c.MoveNext()
>   +486    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +93
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +52    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>   +59    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<ValidateUserName>d__4.MoveNext() +592    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +93
>
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +52    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<ValidateAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
>   +283    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +93
>
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +52    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<CreateAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
>   +582    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +93
>
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +52    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<CreateAsync>d__d.MoveNext()
>   +531    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +93
>
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +52    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>   +24    AutomatedTellerMachine.Controllers.d__9.MoveNext() in e:\Passion\Work\AutomatedTellerMachine\AutomatedTellerMachine\Controllers\AccountController.cs:82
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +93
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +52
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +84
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.b__36(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +17
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +32
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>   +50    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   +225    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +34
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
>   +26    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +100
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +27
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +36
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +28
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +36
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +31    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +9514812    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Comment: could you provide some stacktrace of error?

Comment: There is no way that `user` is null here.

Comment: Sir, I debugged , There was no value in user. that's why line 82 giving me an error .

Comment: It may be that `UserManager` is null, but the only way `user` is null is if the constructor of `ApplicationUser` threw an exception, but as you don't have a try/catch, that is not possible.

Comment: From stack trace it looks like there is a problem with connection with DB not the null value anywhere

Comment: I just installed a fresh ASP.net MVC project using community visual studio 2015 on windows 7and I'm receiving this error. This is the only other instance of someone having this exact issue. Have been looking for hours, and found no cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace shows that your application cannot connect to your database:

> SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - **Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.**)

Note the highlighted section: This indicated that you don't have `LocalDb` installed. Either [install it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh510202.aspx) or change your connection string to point to a database that does exist.

Comment: Sir, I have no idea on context. I am very new at MVC 5 and Entity Framework. I installed EF through NuGet. After that i started to create my project. In the mean time i have done nothing with web.config. Nothing with DB also.

Comment: Then I suggest you do some learning before you continue any further.

Comment: public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>

    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection" )
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
        public DbSet<CheckingAccount> CheckingAccounts { get; set; } 
    }
}

Sir, Are You Talking About It?

Comment: Looking deeper at the error, it also looks like you don't have LocalDb installed...

Comment: @AtiburRahman You should probably note that comments are not meant for posting large chunks of code. If someone asks you for more information, it's generally better to edit your question to include the relevant parts.

Comment: Thank You. I will make it right from next time. Can someone give me some efficient tutorial on mvc 5 and EF.

Comment: Sir, I went deeper in my code and tried to connect with database. Right now i am having  'EntityValidationErrors'.

Comment: @TiesonT. noted that . Thank You

Answer (score -1):

```
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +357
```